# ApiException which checking for location settings in FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using Google Fused Api to retrieve location in my app. So as usual before request location updates I checking for location settings status using `mSettingsClient?.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)`. This seems to be working on every device but on vivo v7 it doesn't work it gives this exception `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Not implemented on this platform.` I tested this with location provider and it's working in that.

I am not able to find any reason behind this.